# Сквозная аутентификация Windows

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2

Скажите, есть ли возможность настроить сквозную аутентификацию Windows? Мне нужно, чтобы в интрасети пользователи одного с сервером домена, были автоматически аутентифицированы под своими учетными данными.